# .map is not a function in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, javascript, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am trying to normalize a data set. But getting an error with

> .map is not a function

How can I solve this issue?

```js
var StRain = raindata.subtract(ltamean).divide(ltastd);

var SPI = StRain.map(function(image){
  var Imin = StRain.reduce(ee.Reducer.min())
  var Imax =StRain.reduce(ee.Reducer.max()) 
    return image.expression('1-(Ia-Imin)/(Imax-Imin)',
      {Ia: image,
       Imin: Imin,
       Imax:Imax
        }).clip(AOI).rename('SPI')
        .copyProperties(image, ['system:time_start'])
        .set('date', image.date().format('YYYY_MM_dd'))
})
```

Comment: as an aside, should `StRain.reduce(...)` inside the map function  be `image.reduce(...)`? Currently, you are performing an identical operation for every image in the collection. Otherwise, it should be outside of `map()`

Comment: The behavior depends on the type of object `raindata`. Could you define it in the example code (perhaps using an asset from the Earth Engine public data catalog)?

Answer (score 1):

I believe `StRain` is an Image and not an ImageCollection, and therefore has no `map()` method.

Comment: I derived from this collection ee.ImageCollection(**'UCSB-CHG/CHIRPS/PENTAD'**). After that I standardized the data (StRain).

Comment: Can you please include the code that results in `StRain` in your question? It would make it easier to see what is happening. (Namely, how `raindata`, `ltamean` and `ltastd` are created from the original ImageCollection)